# Why I can't boot anymore?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, post

my problem started 15 weeks ago (December 17, 2017), when my PC had trouble to boot, the POST message said that I had a CPU fan error, then shut down. I tried to reboot but no avail. I swap the CPU fan, then a red light appeared on my Mobo over the MEM OK! I pressed the small button then the light flashed, then remained red. I tried to reboot this time the other fans did spin for a second, then nothing... no power at all. I ordered a new Mobo (the same brand F2A85-M/CSM), I installed it and the same problem occurred; then I bought new RAMs... nothing; I bought a new CPU, guess? Nothing. I bought a new PSU, the fans started to spins at full speed... (yeah! little improvement, I guessed). I bought a new heatsink (CoolerMaster Hyper 212X)... I can't reach POST. I reinstalled everything over 10 times and NOTHING. Then I read that it may be a dead CMOS battery can cause a system not to respond; I bought a new CMOS battery, I clear the CMOS by unplugging the PC and removing the old battery. I waited half-hour before to plug and boot my PC, then I saw POST on my screen (I was delighted for a moment) and everything freeze, I tried a reboot then the same problem nothing on my screen. I retried to clear the CMOS by 20 times at least... I AM STUCK. (Should I, again and again reinstall everything for 100 times?)

Someone help me, please?

There's my specs;

24" Samsung monitor;
Fractal Design Define R5 Blackout Edition mid-tower case;
ASUS F2A85-M/CSM motherboard;
APU A10 6800K Richland Black Edition;
16GB Kingston HyperX Genesis RAM (4x4GB);
850 Watts Rosewill PSU;
2GB Zotac GT-630 128-bits GPU;
LG M-Disk 16x Blu-Ray burner;
1GB Toshiba 2.5" HDD;
2GB Seagate 3.5" HDD;
1GB Seagate 3.5" HDD.

Thanks.

Comment: Since it started like a memory failure at the 2nd stage, have you tested each memory stick individually? In this case, you have to use a minimal setup. You can use the integrated GPU, and the main disk. Did you O.C. with these memory modules? Did those work earlier (all the sticks without a problem)? 

What did you see in the post? Anything unusual? Are you able to get to the BIOS setup?

Did you install the processor and the heatsink properly?

Comment: No overclocking, my RAMs was working great before that CPU fan failure, the POST freeze at ASUS logo and my PS/2 keyboard too. I'm not able to access BIOS with delete or F2 key. It's 5 time that I reinstalled the processor and the heatsink, properly and yes I re-plugged the CPU 4-pins connectors (the right one), I re-cleared the CMOS to factory default maybe over 10 times already. I boot with extreme  minimal setup, CPU and monitor cord; I wanted to see error messages but still nothing. I don't have an internal beeper (I ordered it. It should arrive by the end of the week). So what's next?

Comment: I swapped RAM; I used the one in the second slot and put it it the first then I used only that module. I could reach POST with error messages. 0 keyboard, 0 drive, 0 mouse... my keyboard froze (I couldn't press F1 key to set the BIOS... It seem that the first module is dead. I will try the third one and the fourth to see if they function...

Comment: No luck, same problem. I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Have you installed BIOS updates? BIOS updates are likely to cause such issues (even if it is too old or new with bugs).  If not, that indicates the problem was already there (either a peripheral or PSU but in your case you had also updated the PSU). If you try with a single memory stick, stock GPU, and other basic things such as one boot device and no other extra drives, then the problem is caused by one of these devices (I still don't think its the mobo as it sounds new although there are cases). By any chance are you able to try with a USB keyboard if you can borrow?

Comment: I can't do anything with my Blu-Ray drive, I have the motherboard DVD, with Linux boot included and nothing, the light flash from my drive so it's working. I can't do a thing. I tried only with the APU and monitor only; and it freeze at ASUS logo. I have a USB adapter to plug my PS/2 keyboard and I tried all the USB plugs the only thing is that all the 3 lights on my keyboard remains lit and it's frozen. It had to be the new APU; I tried with the old one and it was worst nothing on the screen. My best bet is to wait the internal beeper to arrive. Until then it's like to shot ducks blindfolded

Comment: I installed the internal speaker. The speaker beep at POST; the keyboard is unresponsive, I see the ASUS logo and there's nothing... black screen. I ear my HDD working, the fans spins at full speed. I try to permute the RAM stick to different slot 16 times I reinstalled the APU by 3 times, cleared the memory... nothing. Can it be a compatibility issue between the mobo and the PSU... It's a  discontinued mobo. I wonder if that motherboard is powerful enough to power that kind of CPU even if they are compatible. Any good suggestion is welcomed at this point.